# Trouble installing units package for use of tmap package

Tags: r, units-of-measurement, tmap

I am trying to use tmap and other mapping and spatial statistics packages. When I try to load the library for tmap, I get an error:

```
    library(tmap)
    Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
      there is no package called ‘units’
    In addition: Warning message:
    package ‘tmap’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’

    Then I tried installing the units package with and without dependencies.
```

I get the same error when trying to install it either way.

```
    install.packages("units", dependencies = FALSE)
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/hello/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

    There is a binary version available but the source version
     is later:
    binary source needs_compilation
    units  0.5-1  0.6-0             FALSE

    installing the source package ‘units’

    trying URL 'https://muug.ca/mirror/cran/src/contrib/units_0.6-0.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 912393 bytes (891 KB)
    downloaded 891 KB

    * installing *source* package 'units' ...
    ** package 'units' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

       **********************************************
       WARNING: this package has a configure script
             It probably needs manual configuration
       **********************************************


    ** libs

    *** arch - i386
    Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="units.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o io.o udunits.o"' had status 127
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'units'
    * removing 'C:/Users/hello/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/units'
    Warning in install.packages :
      running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\hello\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0QIIHG/downloaded_packages/units_0.6-0.tar.gz' had status 1
    Warning in install.packages :
     installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status

    The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0QIIHG\downloaded_packages’
```

Any help with this would be great!

Answer (score 4):

I was just having the same problem, then I tried `install.packages("units", type='binary')` and was then able to install and load tmap.

Comment: this solution unfortunately doesn't work for HPC systems, which don't support binary

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to install this package. I tried "install.packages("units", type='binary') " but it continued to give the same error. So then I installed from terminal the following and then tried to install in R so the units package could be installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev
```

Got this packages from this issue.

[How to solve "Error: libudunits2.a not found" when installing "udunits2" in R 3.6.0 from Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234169/how-to-solve-error-libudunits2-a-not-found-when-installing-udunits2-in-r-3)